# MQTT client.publish() and delay()

Tags: arduino, delay, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I have a small local IoT network with a handful of Wemos D1 nodes programmed in the Arduino IDe. Some of them have two sensors connected, e.g. rain and humidity.
I want to send out values every minute, one minute the rain, one minute the humidity.
Below code generally works with `delay(5000);` for both, but once I have something like `delay(60000);` the node apparently starts only publishing the rain and skips the humidity (I have a `mosquitto_sub -h myIP -v -t '#'` running to listen for messaged.

This is my `loop()` where all the sensing and sending happens:

```cpp
void loop() {
    if (!client.connected() && WiFi.status() == 3) {
        reconnect();
    }
    client.loop();

    int val = digitalRead(rainSensor);     // read the input pin
    rain_str = String(val);
    rain_str.toCharArray(rain, rain_str.length() + 1); 
    client.publish(rainTopic, rain);
    delay(60000);

    int val2 = analogRead(humidSensor);     // read the input pin
    humid_str = String(val2);
    humid_str.toCharArray(humid, humid_str.length() + 1);
    client.publish(humidTopic, humid);
    delay(60000);
}
```

Comment: Maybe your connection gets closed after waiting 60 seconds? Did you add `Serial` debugging to determine the state of the `client` object (`boolean PubSubClient::connected()`) and if reaches the code after the `delay()`?

Comment: Just a note: instead of `humid_str.toCharArray(humid, humid_str.length() + 1); client.publish(humidTopic, humid);` you may use `client.publish(humidTopic, humid_str.c_str())`, or you may directly use `sprintf()` of `val2` over `humid`, the latter being declared of type `char[]` with sufficiently large size, avoiding dynamic memory usage caused by `String` altogether.

Comment: You may get more traction on http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You will get a MQTT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT if you are not calling the client.loop() function within MQTT_KEEPALIVE seconds (typically 15 s).

Make sure to call the client.loop() with much shorter interval. Use a counter to to count to 60 or better use a timer function like the Ticker library.