# ESP32 MQTT and Influxdb interfere with connection

Tags: mqtt, esp32, influxdb, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

so I try to automate a little project with my esp32 Devkit (wroom 32).
Short-Version:

1. ESP32 Setup Wifi / MQTT connection + Sub to Topic (listen for callback on topic)
2. Esp32 reads the analog Value of my sensor which is connected per GPIO
3. Esp32 writes value to influxdb -> at this point the connection with the MQTT disconnected?
4. If certain String "low_humidity" comes via topic "prototype2" then (only for test) it should flash the onboard LED (and print the string)

Point 4. never happends (I try to listen to the topic on other devices, no Problem, also I set the QoS to 1 for the mqtt message)
If I delete the influxdb part "Point pointDevice("sensor_data"); .... to ....pointDevice.clearTags(); " it works.
Also the ESP32 is constantly reconnction to mqtt, here the serial output(print):

```
22:26:05.074 -> Moisture value:3457
22:26:05.074 -> written to local InfluxDB instance:1
22:26:05.231 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
22:26:05.231 -> resubbed...
22:26:10.549 -> Moisture value:3474
22:26:10.549 -> written to local InfluxDB instance:1
22:26:10.595 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
22:26:10.689 -> resubbed...
22:26:16.010 -> Moisture value:3486
22:26:16.010 -> written to local InfluxDB instance:1
22:26:16.040 -> Attempting MQTT connection...connected
22:26:16.087 -> resubbed...
```

and the code:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <InfluxDbClient.h>


#define AOUT_PIN 36 // ESP32 pin GPIO36 (ADC0) that connects to AOUT pin of sensor


WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

#define LED 2

//JsonDocument data;


void callback(char* topic, byte* message, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print(". Message: ");
  String messageTemp = "";


  for (int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    messageTemp= messageTemp + (char)message[i];
  }

  Serial.println("Ouput Raw:");
  Serial.println(messageTemp);

  if(messageTemp =="low_humidity"){
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
  }
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect("", "demo", "demo")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      //client.publish("prototype","esp32 online");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("prototype2",1);
      Serial.println("resubbed...");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initWiFi();
  Serial.print("RRSI: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());

  timeSync(TZ_INFO, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nis.gov");

  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT); //LED Pin in Output Mode

  Serial.println("Setting up MQTT ...");
  client.setServer(MQTT_SERVER, MQTT_PORT);
  boolean connected= client.connect("", "demo", "demo");
  client.setCallback(callback);
  client.subscribe("prototype2",1);
  Serial.println("Sub to Topic ...proto...");
  Serial.println("MQTT set up complete...");
  Serial.print("Connection Status: ");
  Serial.println(connected);

}


void loop() {
  int value = analogRead(AOUT_PIN); // read the analog value from sensor
  delay(300);

  Serial.print("Sensor value:");
  Serial.println(value);
   
  
   Point pointDevice("sensor_data"); // create a new measurement point (the same point can be used for Cloud and v1 InfluxDB)
 // Serial.println("setConnection");
  //influx_client.setConnectionParamsV1(INFLUXDB_URL, "IoT");

  //Serial.println("Connection done");
  pointDevice.addTag("sensor_name", "analog_sensor_1");
  pointDevice.addField("analog_value_humidity", value);
  Serial.print("written to local InfluxDB instance:");
  InfluxDBClient influx_client(INFLUXDB_URL, "demo");
  Serial.println(influx_client.writePoint(pointDevice)); // returns true if success, false otherwise
  pointDevice.clearFields();
  pointDevice.clearTags(); 

   if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  client.loop();
  delay(5000);

}
```

I try to listen and write to both services mqtt and influxdb without the need to reconnect all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MQTT client.publish() and delay()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533152/mqtt-client-publish-and-delay) (it's worse in your case because without more calls to `loop` the library will not process incoming messages).